# Linear model, ordinary least squares $\mathbb E||\hat\beta||^2$

Tags: statistics

I need to prove that in a linear model, least squares estimator $\hat \beta$:

$\mathbb E||\hat\beta||^2=||\beta||^2+\sigma^2\sum_1^p\lambda_i^{-1}$ where $\lambda $ denotes eigenvalues of $X'X$.

So:

$\mathbb E||\hat\beta||^2=\mathbb E[\hat\beta'\hat\beta]=\mathbb E[Y'X(X'X)^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}X'Y]=\mathbb E[(\beta'X'+e')X(X'X)^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}X'(X\beta+e)]=\dots=\mathbb E[\beta'\beta+e'X(X'X)^{-1}\beta+\beta'(X'X)^{-1}X'e+e'X(X'X)^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}X'e]=||\beta||^2+0+0+\mathbb E[e'X(X'X)^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}X'e]$

as $\mathbb E[e']=\mathbb E[e]=0$. I guess I'd like to make use of the fact that $\mathbb E[e'e]=\sigma^2(n-p)$ or $H=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ but I don't really know how to proceed from where I am.

Comment: I think that you can see this post where you find how is the relationship into the eigenvalues and the $X' X$ matrix. 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970459/linear-regression-how-does-multicollinearity-inflate-variance-of-estimators?rq=1

Comment: @AlexPozo thanks! So I have $\mathbb E[e'X(X'X)^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}X'e]=\mathbb E[e'XU\lambda^{-1}\lambda^{-1}U'X'e]=\mathbb E[(X'e)'X'e]\sum_i^p\lambda^{-1}$ but don't really know what to do with this expression $E[(X'e)'X'e]$ apart from the fact that it equals $\mathbb E[\|X'e\|]$